# String.replace() isn't working like I expect

Tags: java, string, replace

I am not understanding how to use the String.replace() method. Here is the code:

```
    CharSequence oldNumber = "0";
    CharSequence newNumber = "1";
    String example = "folderName_0";
    System.out.println("example = " + example);
    example.replace(oldNumber, newNumber);
    System.out.println("example.replace(oldNumber, newNumber);");
    System.out.println("example = " + example);
```

And it's outputting:

```
example = folderName_0
example.replace(oldNumber, newNumber);
example = folderName_0 // <=== How do I make this folderName_1???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method isn't changing the contents of your string; `String`s are immutable.  It's returning a new string that contains the changed contents, but you've ignored the returned value.  Change

```
example.replace(oldNumber, newNumber);
```

with

```
example = example.replace(oldNumber, newNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. You need to re-assign the returned value of `replace` to the variable:

```
example = example.replace(oldNumber, newNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

String is a immutable object, when you are trying to change your string with the help of this code - `example.replace(oldNumber,newNumber);` it changed your string but it will be a new string and you are not holding that new string into any variable. Either you can hold this new string into a new variable, if you want to use your old string value later in your code like -

```
String changedValue = example.replace(oldNumber,newNumber);
```

or you can store in the existing string if you are not going to use your old string value later like -

```
example = example.replace(oldNumber,newNumber);
```